# How to create a custom attribute for group contact Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am using the below code to create a group contact in Android. However, it only provides two attributes: name and Id. Can we add more attribute for the group? If it is possible, can we create a custom attribute for the group, such as color of group? How can we get the custom attribute from the added group. Thank all

```
public String createGroup(String name) {

            String[] GROUP_PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.Groups._ID,     ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE };

            try {
                ContentValues groupValues = null;
                ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
                groupValues = new ContentValues();
                groupValues.put(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, name);
                groupValues.put(ContactsContract.Groups.SHOULD_SYNC,true);
                cr.insert(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, groupValues);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("########### Exception :",""+e.getMessage());
                return "1";
            }

            String groupID = null;
            Cursor getGroupID_Cursor = null;
            getGroupID_Cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,  GROUP_PROJECTION, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE+ "=?", new String[]{name}, null);

            getGroupID_Cursor.moveToFirst();
            groupID = (getGroupID_Cursor.getString(getGroupID_Cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));

            return groupID;


        }
```